# Typescript error tsc.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: typescript

I am using VS 2015 update 3. I have installed Typescript tools 2.0.6 for visual studio. I keep getting the error

```
Error   MSB6006 "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.   ReportBook.Web  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 222
```

So I did a little digging and found something rather curious:

```
Unknown output: Cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.0\tsc.js'.
```

So I decided to check the file location and there was no tsc.js file there. I cant figure out what this is all about and I am yet to find any answers online.
Hope somebody would help me out with some information on how to get past this one

Answer (score 1):

Really you installed the Type Script package? try to reinstall the package, the file tsc.js should be there.

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too. The problem was that in my batch script. Since I am using Typescript, before calling `msbuild.exe` I did a full search of all `.js` files and delete them.

Not only application `.js` where deleted, but also the tsc.js itself inside the TypScript package folder.

You need to make sure to ignore the subfolder package before delete all .js files! :-)